# Water stained tiles

Tags: flooring, tile, cleaning, ceramic-tile

A few years ago, I purchased a foreclosed home and it seems that on some areas water was leaking from the roof onto the tiles and they have [stained](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ne5w.jpg). I've tried scrubbing with bleach and other household ingredients and have managed to remove some of the calcium deposits, but the stain is still there.

[image]

I would like some recommendations on how to salvage them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is calcium carbonate, "lime", then there are [numerous commercial product](https://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_ss_sc_1_10?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=limescale%20remover)s to remove it. Some products are specifically suggested for use on tile.

If you want to try home remedies, start with distilled vinegar, which is comparatively safe for construction materials and for people. The strongest chemicals, such as [hydrochloric acid (muriatic acid, HCl)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B008285YY4), are corrosive, have toxic fumes and are likely to damage grout and wood, if not ceramic tile itself.

After cleaning, be sure to [seal the tile](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00ILY6SI0) to improve appearance and to make further damage less likely.

N.B. Links are to show examples of commercial products, but are not recommendations.